# Is there a way to save what substr does to a string in a new var?

Tags: php

If you have the following string:

```
$something = 'abcdefg';
$cut = substr( $something, 0, -2);
```

result:
abcde

Is there a way to store the cut part into a new var, so in this example, save 'fg', before removing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$something = 'abcdefg';
$cut = substr( $something, 0, -2);    // abcde
$endBit = substr($something, -2);     // fg
```

Check the manual for all the gory details: [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)